# Update a column to remove stop words from another table SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having problems with the following code and I was wondering if anyone could help me resolve this issue. I have two tables, `tbl` and `stopwords` which you can recreate with the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE stopwords(
  stopword char(100) NOT NULL
);
insert into stopwords values ('I');
insert into stopwords values ('in');
insert into stopwords values ('on');
insert into stopwords values ('of');
insert into stopwords values ('to');
insert into stopwords values ('a');
insert into stopwords values ('too');

CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id INT,
  message TEXT
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, 'in in in in of of of of on too we are on top of the world'),
(2, 'too bad the apple is rotten'),
(3, 'there is no I in team but a man thinks'),
(4, 'it matters where you go to a random');
```

I want to update the message column in tbh while removing each stopword from the stopwords table. However, I want to do this process iteratively, instead of manually writing out an update statement for each stopword.

I tried the following query and no errors occur but the message column does not update to anything and does not return any errors.

```
update tbl 
SET message = TRIM(
  REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', REPLACE(message, sw.stopword, sw.stopword), ' '), sw.stopword, '')
)
from stopwords as sw
where CONCAT(' ', message , ' ')  like CONCAT('%' ,sw.stopword , '%');
```

Can anyone help me with debugging this?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: So your expected output into tbl would be all the words in the text less the words in the stopwords table?  `Example: 1) we are top the world` would be the result

Comment: @xQbert yes exactly

Comment: Wow.... so we would have to split each line into it's own rows by word keeping track or the order and then re-combine it into a vlaue then update the table.  I think... since if you just "replace" when you replace "a" your word `are` becomes `re`  yeah this will be a db secific solution likely as it involves splititng out data into multiple rows and recombining multiple rows back into 1.  Tricky; but doable I think.  List_Agg or String_Agg recursive cte to split a row into multiple...

Comment: SQL replace only replaces one group at a time. You can nest them.

Comment: @Kendle I don't think replace will work.  If we replace 'a' with '' then 'are' becomes 're' and it shouldn't be affected.  you might be able to do it with adding a space; but then you have to deal with first and/or last words. and possibly other edge cases.

Comment: still waiting to know what the RDBMS is...

Comment: As xQbert mentioned, we don't know your RDBMS. This works in postgres, and pretty simple as long as your list is not too long...  regexp_replace(t1.message, '\y(I|in|on|of|to|a|too)\y', '', 'g'). This will replace all instances of the exact word with nothing.

Comment: @xQbert the DB I use is Snowflake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a function. We start by adding a space before and after the line. We then loop through the words from stopwords with replace with space. We keep running each replace until the length after the remove is the same as before it. Finally we use `TRIM` to remove the spaces before and after the string.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE stopwords(
>   stopword char(100) NOT NULL
> );
> insert into stopwords values ('I');
> insert into stopwords values ('in');
> insert into stopwords values ('on');
> insert into stopwords values ('of');
> insert into stopwords values ('to');
> insert into stopwords values ('a');
> insert into stopwords values ('too');
>
> CREATE TABLE tbl (
>   id INT,
>   message TEXT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
> (1, 'in in in in of of of of on too we are on top of the world'),
> (2, 'too bad the apple is rotten'),
> (3, 'there is no I in team but a man thinks'),
> (4, 'it matters where you go to a random');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> ✓

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> create  function removeStop(raw_string varchar(100))
>    returns varchar(100)
>    language plpgsql
>   as
> $$
> declare 
>    raw_str varchar(100);
>    pat varchar(10);
>    l1 int; l2 int;
>    tRow record;
> -- variable declaration
> begin
>   raw_str = concat(' ',raw_string,' ');
>   for tRow in
>   select stopword s from stopwords
>   loop
>     pat = concat(' ',trim(from tRow.s),' ');
>     l1=1000;l2=length(raw_str);
>     while l1>l2 loop
>       l1=l2;
>       raw_str = replace(raw_str,pat,' ');
>       l2 = length(raw_str);
>     end loop;
>   end loop;
>   return trim(from raw_str);
>   --return pat;
> -- logic
> end;
> $$
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | message                                                  
> -: | :--------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | in in in in of of of of on too we are on top of the world
>  2 | too bad the apple is rotten                              
>  3 | there is no I in team but a man thinks                   
>  4 | it matters where you go to a random
> ```

> ```
> update tbl set message=removeStop(message);
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | message                        
> -: | :------------------------------
>  1 | we are top the world           
>  2 | bad the apple is rotten        
>  3 | there is no team but man thinks
>  4 | it matters where you go random
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b0632ce582d998174a3c92f9521bfb13)*

Comment: nice.  I was trying to avoid a function call but this is elegant